# AngularJS: Returning "Subsets" of Data from a Factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this factory:

```
(function(){

    var requestsFactory = function(){

        var requests = [
          {id: 1, title: 'First Request', status: 'In Progress'},
          {id: 2, title: 'Second Request', status: 'Closed'},
          {id: 3, title: 'Third Request', status: 'Waiting'},
          {id: 4, title: 'Fourth Request', status: 'Closed'},
          {id: 5, title: 'Fifth Request', status, 'In Progress'}
        ];

        var factory = {};

        factory.getAllRequests = function(){ return requests; };
        /* THIS IS NEW */
        factory.getOpenRequests = function(){
          var open_requests = filter(requests.status, function(status){
            return status !== 'Closed';
          });
          return open_requests;
        };
        /* END NEW */

       return factory;
}; // end requestsFactory

        return factory;
    };

    angular.module('appITI').factory('requestsFactory', requestsFactory);
}());
```

And this Controller:

```
(function(){

    var UsersController = function($scope, usersFactory, requestsFactory){
        $scope.current_user = [];
        $scope.requests = [];
        $scope.open_requests = []; // NEW

        $scope.prefs = 'false';

        function init(){
            $scope.current_user = usersFactory.getCurrentUser();
            $scope.requests = requestsFactory.getAllRequests();
             $scope.open_requests = requestsFactory.getOpenRequests(); //NEW
        }

        init();

    }; // end UsersController

    UsersController.$inject = ['$scope', 'usersFactory', 'requestsFactory'];

    angular.module('appITI').controller('UsersController', UsersController);

}());
```

I need to add a method to the factory so that I can call something like this in the controller:

```
$scope.open_requests = requestsFactory.requestsByStatus('In Progress');
```

I have been so absorbed with learning AngularJs this weekend I can't seem to figure out what I bet is simple JavaScript.

NEW
I have this in the template and now the page is white and broken.

```
<tr class="landing_data_row" data-ng-repeat="request in open_requests | filter:techFilter | orderBy:sortBy:reverse">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new function to your factory, and use the `filter` function.

```
factory.getOpenRequests = function(){
  return requests.filter(function(el){
    return el.status !== 'Closed';
  });
};
```

**update**
Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LxL7sWRWbgYJW9g6Is57?p=preview) to your updated question.

Comment: Is that the "filter" from Angular? Because, if it is, I am already giving the user a textbox to filter the data to easily find what they are looking for ... will they conflict?

Comment: No, standard javascript functionality.

Comment: crap! my brain is so filled up with videos, books, and lessons on AngularJS this weekend, I am almost useless ... THANKS!!! ... one other thing, can I put a switch statement in that so that I don't have to rewrite a function for each call on Status? The status choices are a finite set of 7 possibilities.

Comment: Of course you can :) Write it as a function taking in parameters.

Comment: please see updated question ... the page is blank and a referenceError of filter is not defined ... did I screw up?

Comment: I don't see your question is updated with the filter function. If you set up a fiddle I'll take a look at it for you

Comment: I just saved my changes ... sorry.

Comment: You had a typo in your filter function, maybe that solves it ;) If not, i'll look at your fiddle.

Comment: the missing 's' didn't help ... here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7seeDGN4xVV0jBvpf4uD?p=preview and THANKS FOR HELPING!!!

Comment: @jgravois now its working as expected. See my updated answer.